# Proxy server not running in Angular 6

Tags: angular, proxy, angular-cli

Am trying to set up a proxy server in my Angular 6 app, but it is not re-routing my request. Here are the sample files from my app.

**service.ts**

```js
this.apiURL = 'https://www.example.com/xyzServices/api/getUser';
```

**proxy.conf.json**

```json
{
  "/api/": {
    "target": "https://www.example.com/",
    "secure": true,
    "logLevel": "info",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Is there something that is not right/missing here?

Answer (score 0):

1. API URL should be target to your localhost.

```ts
this.apiURL = `/xyzServices/api/getUser`
```

2. Set matching string in the front part.

```json
{
  "/xyzServices": {
    "target": "https://www.example.com",
    "secure": true,
    "logLevel": "info",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```